# Windows Phone back button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I need to go back to a particular page when I click on a button. more like custom back button.

I can go exact page, if I know what is the page is,

```
private void button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page1));
}
```

Also I can go back to the previous page by

```
if(this.Frame.CanGoBack)
{
    Frame.GoBack();
}
```

But how can I jump to the page before the previous page at once?

Any record of page history?

Comment: `windows-mobile` is not the correct tag if you meant `windows phone 8.1`, in which case, please correct it with the `windows-phone-8.1` tag.

Comment: I think this can be addressed by simply calling `if (Frame.CanGoBack) Frame.GoBack()` twice. Frame maintains the history (the stack of pages).

Comment: Yeah, its an option. but it's like a hard code. Isn't it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394012(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: @iJay Oh, now I understand the requirement is _"jumping at once"_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @CoderDennis, I figured it out. hope it will help to someone else.
I wanted to move back to the Main page if I have come along the Main page,

```
foreach (PageStackEntry stack in Frame.BackStack)
{
 //check if stack contains history of the main page. (Solution name: Helloworld)
 if (stack.SourcePageType == typeof(HelloWorld.MainPage))
   {
    Frame.Navigate(stack.SourcePageType);
    break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NavigationServices.BackStack` to access on an history of your previous pages.

But you have not specific method to go back from 2 pages at once. However, if you would jump to the page before the previous page you have just to called `NavigationServices.GoBack()` two times.

Moreover, if you would go back to a specific page, you can know its index between backstack and make a loop with the `GoBack` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all pages from BackStack as a List :

```
var lstAllStackPages = this.Frame.BackStack.ToList();
```

and make a for loop to get your specific page and navigate to it.